# enryption Algorithm of qs parameter generated by adding %%view_email_url%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, cloudpagesurl, view

By adding "%%view_email_url%%" to your send email, an HTML anchor like this will be the outcome. "http://view.email.domain/?qs=cf22e6f54fe6a6a5fe.....

i know that the qs parameter is the encrypted url parameters concatenated, because i managed to decompose the qs hash that i have into three parts (three parameters) and it was possible for me to replace the hash of each parameter and qs still be valid.
i want to know what algorithm is used to encrypt these parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method used is 3DES, but please note Marketing Cloud only uses it for obfuscation purposes, not for encryption. The information the Marketing Cloud obfuscates is not private, and the Query String parameter is simply a method to bundle several parameters together that the page uses.

It is not possible to access/obtain the keys used for this algorithm, hence it is not possible to decrypt the query string outside of the standard functionality of the platform. The parameters passed in the query string are a.o. the standard [personalization strings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5), and can be accessed using the [RequestParameter()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) function of Ampscript.

Comment: hello @Lukas Lunow ty for answer ,where is the 3des key located ? for example in this using %%view_email_url%% what key is it using for the encryption?

Comment: @samuelsamuelll I have added more details to my answer